# Search SubDocument Object ID in Mongoose Schema with find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a getting the problem when querying with embedded object ID

Here is my Activity Type schema

```
  const ActivityTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     activity_name: {
        type: String
     }
  }
```

Here is my Activity schema

```
  const ActivitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     activity_type: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'activity_type',
     },
     location: {
       type: String
     },
     start_time: {
       type: String
     },
     end_time: {
       type: String
     }
  }
```

My code

```
   let regex = new RegExp(req.query.searchString, "i");

   let getActivities = await Activity.find({
      'location': regex,
      'activity_type.activity_name': regex
   });
```

In Result, am getting an empty array []

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: In Result, getting empty array []

Comment: That is expected. ActivityType is of type ObjectId. It stores a reference to the not object, not the object itself. Either store the object directly or try writing an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: i already use the pipeline, but result is same

let getActivities = await Activity.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "activity_type",
          "localField": "activity_type",
          "foreignField": "id",
          "as": "activity_type_docs"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$activity_type_docs"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "order_docs.activity_name": {
            "$regex": regex,
            "$options": "i"
          }
        }
      }
    ])

Comment: Within `$match`, `order_docs.activity_name` should be `activity_type_docs.activity_name`

Comment: this is the actual code and result is empty, can you please check this;

    let getActivities = await Activity.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "activity_type",
          "localField": "activity_type",
          "foreignField": "id",
          "as": "activity_type_docs"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$activity_type_docs"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "activity_type_docs.activity_name": {
            "$regex": regex,
            "$options": "i"
          }
        }
      }
    ])

Comment: please share some input documents from both collections. Along with the value you are looking for

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996286/search-subdocument-object-id-in-mongoose-schema-with-find)

I written a elaborated question, please go through it. Your response is appreciated