# Search SubDocument Object ID in Mongoose Schema with find

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm looking for the solution, where I can do text search on documents or referenced document.

Here is my Activity Type schema

```
 const ActivityTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     activity_name: {
       type: String
     }
  }
```

Here is my Activity schema

```
  const ActivitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       activity_type: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'activity_type',
       },
       location: {
          type: String
       },
       start_time: {
          type: String
       },
       end_time: {
          type: String
       }
   }
```

Here is the Data from my collection activity_type

```
[
  {
   "_id": { "$oid": "633f10f3386b79ac054cffff" },
   "activity_name": "Pushing",
  },
  {
   "_id": { "$oid": "633f10f3386b79ac054ccccc" },
   "activity_name": "Gymming",
  }
]
```

Here is the Data from my collection activity

```
[
  {
   "_id": { "$oid": "633db6c1715278070bc9b94c" },
    activity_type": { "$oid": "633f10f3386b79ac054cffff" },
    "start_time": "09:00",
    "end_time": "12:00",
    "location": "Dubai"
  },
  {
   "_id": { "$oid": "633db6c1715278070bc9b896" },
    activity_type": { "$oid": "633f10f3386b79ac054ccccc" },
    "start_time": "09:00",
    "end_time": "12:00",
    "location": "USA"
  }
]
```

This is what I have tried but getting an empty [] error.

```
  let getActivities = await Activity.aggregate([
    {
       "$lookup": {
          "from": "activity_type",
          "localField": "activity_type",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "activity_type_docs"
        }
    },
    {
       "$unwind": "$activity_type_docs"
    },
    {
       "$match": {
           "activity_type_docs.activity_name": {
           "$regex": regex,
           "$options": "i"
          }
        }
     }
])
```

Expected Output on text search

By activity_name i.e Gymming

```
[
   {
     _id: 633db6c1715278070bc9b94c,
     is_deleted: false,
     activity_type: { _id: 633f10f3386b79ac054cffff, activity_name: 'Gymming' },
     start_time: '09:00',
     end_time: '12:00',
     location: 'Dubai'
   }
]
```

OR
By location i.e Dubai

```
[
   {
     _id: 633db6c1715278070bc9b94c,
     is_deleted: false,
     activity_type: { _id: 633f10f3386b79ac054cffff, activity_name: 'Gymming' },
     start_time: '09:00',
     end_time: '12:00',
     location: 'Dubai'
   }
]
```

Comment: Seems to be working here https://mongoplayground.net/p/3vzPbp0Sjbp. How are you generating the value of regex in your code

Comment: i use this; let regex = new RegExp(req.query.searchString, "i");

Comment: Simply pass `regex.query.searchString`, that should do it.

Comment: when I'm trying only lookup aggregation, activity_type_docs coming as empty array, it seams to have a problem as we are using ref in activity schema as mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Comment: That shouldn't cause any trouble as the `_id` in `activity_type` will also be of type `ObjectId`.

Comment: Thanks alot, its worked for me. Highly appreciated for your time.
Thanks again... :)